# ValueError: Too many values to unpack Django

Tags: python, django

So I just got my first django app deployed.

I did a `syncdb` and created my superuser account for the site.

Now when I access the page and press the login button I get this error. I think it has something to do with the password but I'm not sure.

```
ValueError at /accounts/login/
too many values to unpack
```

I'm using the generic login view

```
(r'^accounts/login/$', login, {'template_name': 'authentication/login.html'}),
```

The following is the traceback

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8888/accounts/login/?next=/some_page/

Django Version: 1.3.1
Python Version: 2.7.2
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'bc_system_app',
 'django.contrib.humanize']
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfResponseMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  93.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  79.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/auth/views.py" in login
  35.         if form.is_valid():
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in is_valid
  121.         return self.is_bound and not bool(self.errors)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in _get_errors
  112.             self.full_clean()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in full_clean
  268.         self._clean_form()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in _clean_form
  296.             self.cleaned_data = self.clean()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/auth/forms.py" in clean
  85.             self.user_cache = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py" in authenticate
  55.             user = backend.authenticate(**credentials)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/auth/backends.py" in authenticate
  18.             if user.check_password(password):
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py" in check_password
  275.         return check_password(raw_password, self.password)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py" in check_password
  42.     algo, salt, hsh = enc_password.split('$')

Exception Type: ValueError at /accounts/login/
Exception Value: too many values to unpack
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, there is a problem in the password.

The error is in the way the password has been encrypted and stored in the DB. It can be clearly seen from the statement `algo, salt, hsh = enc_password.split('$')` in the traceback. The encrypted password splitting returns more than 3 values.

So, please have look at the password encryption schemes and related.

Comment: Why is that though? I just did a `syncdb` and created a user when prompted. Also I just looked at the pw hash there's 3 `$`... so that would split into 4...

Comment: I found out what the problem is. I messed up the secret key when I was fiddling with the settings. thanks

Comment: Strange. I am getting exactly the same exception. I changed my secret-key but I am still getting same error.

Comment: @Burak you probably are setting the password in the shell with a different version of django than the one the server is using.

Comment: This is exactly the same error that I have been encountering did anyone find any solutions for this? cause I was thinking of modifying that part right there but it's not really a good idea and I hate to mess up with the django core code

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/10223206/380623 my issue was a Django 1.4 vs 1.3 mismatch.

Answer (score 33):

Just had the same problem.

It seem that in my case, the site was running with Django 1.4 when the password was created (due to a PYTHONPATH mix-up).

When I tried to login running the site with 1.3.1 I got this error. Then I noticed the Django version, switched to 1.4 and the login started working again.

It seems the password algorithm was changed in 1.4:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.4-beta-1/#improved-password-hashing

And if you were using Django 1.4 alpha it might also be that the password was effectively corrupted (read the warning).

Answer (score 18):

The easiest fix is to reset your password from the command line.

```
./manage.py changepassword <user>
```

Answer (score 12):

You can reset the password in the shell.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
u = User.objects.get(username="myuser")
u.set_password("mypassword")
u.save()
```

This happens when we downgrade from 1.4.X to test old deployments as detailed by @h3.

Answer (score 2):

I did everything to solve the same problem. Finally I deleted the db tables, and made syncdb again, creating new superuser. Everything works fine now. The problem is related to bad user data I guess.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.  The password for my superuser was somehow corrupted.  You can check this by examining the auth_user table in your database.  Your password should be something like ""sha1$263a7$c17f83f1d1902fb7bd527d00ffcb22f4dc97a978".  If you have more than (or less than) two "$" symbols, you would get a similar error.  The reason for this, as Sandip mentioned, is because the following function expects three values to be returned:

`algo, salt, hsh = enc_password.split('$')`

Having that extra "$" symbol in your password would return four values and cause the "too many values to unpack" error message to appear.

The solution for me was to create a new superuser by using the createsuperuser command in the manage.py script.  More information about how to create a superuser can be found here:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/

I am still not sure why my password was corrupted.

Comment: I also had this issue. I started with Django 1.4 and then reverted to 1.3 to maintain compatibility with Grappelli. I created my superuser when I installed 1.4 and the default password pattern does not look like it is backwards compatible with 1.3. Deleting my superuser and creating a new one worked for me.