# Python ValueError at /admin/ too many values to unpack

Tags: python, django

HI guys after I click the login button on the admin login page. I get this error:

```
ValueError at /admin/
too many values to unpack
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/admin/
Django Version: 1.3.1
Exception Type: ValueError
Exception Value:    
too many values to unpack
Exception Location: /home/justin/Workspace/training/django/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py in check_password, line 42
Python Executable:  /home/justin/Workspace/training/django/env/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.2
Python Path:    
['/home/justin/Workspace/training/django/test_project',
 '/home/justin/Workspace/training/django/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg',
 '/home/justin/Workspace/training/django/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.1-py2.7.egg',
 '/home/justin/Workspace/training/django/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg',
 '/home/justin/Workspace/training/django/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.1-py2.7.egg',
 '/home/justin/Workspace/training/django/env/lib/python2.7',
 '/home/justin/Workspace/training/django/env/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
 '/home/justin/Workspace/training/django/env/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/home/justin/Workspace/training/django/env/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/home/justin/Workspace/training/django/env/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/home/justin/Workspace/training/django/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/home/justin/Workspace/training/django/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg-info',
 '/home/justin/Workspace/training/django/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/home/justin/Workspace/training/django/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg-info']
Server time:    Thu, 19 Apr 2012 01:36:33 -0500
```

can anyone help me with this? I don't know where is the error.

thanks,
Justin

Comment: Please post the last line of the stacktrace (source code)

Comment: I didn't touch/edit the code for the admin side. I only edit the index template

Comment: Posting the traceback is *not* considered optional...

Comment: can anyone help me? I'm very new with django. I follow the tutorial after following the part 3 tutorial, After it, I tried to login in the admin page then the error shows up after I click the login button.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Probably your stored password is wrong, did you change the secret key in your settings file? Or modified password using Django 1.4 but run on Django 1.3? see this post [ValueError: Too many values to unpack Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8954270/valueerror-too-many-values-to-unpack-django)

Comment: I was having this because of the 1.4 vs 1.3 issue. It's odd because it works fine for some time but it seems once i clear the browser cache that accesses the 1.3 instance, the error appears. Upgrading all instances to 1.4 seems to have solved the issue.